# bitwise mask vs IN() efficiency in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, binary, query-optimization, mask

I have two ways to select a set of entries from the database:

```
  SELECT ... WHERE `level` IN (1,2,4,8) LIMIT ...;
```

or

```
  SELECT ... WHERE `level` & mask LIMIT ...;
```

There are 4 'levels' total, numbered 1,2,4,8 (for reasons of ability to use the same mask elsewhere too). Both the braces of `IN()` or the `mask` can contain any set of one or more of the 4 levels. The column is indexed. The query is still taking way longer than comfortable, and we're trying to optimize it for speed.

Yesterday one person said decided using naive IN() results in up to four comparisons and that I should be using a bit mask instead. Today I heard the bit mask will completely thwart advantages from index on the column, and will be much slower.

Can you tell me which approach will be faster?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your question is quite old but I'm still gonna answer it nonetheless.

The bitmask will most probably be slower as it has to work out the computation of the bitwise AND whereas `IN` will use the **indexed** value of `level` to look it up in the arguments enclosed within the parentheses (which, I believe, should be a single `O(log(n))` operation).

Now, the thing that you may be missing, is that they don't do the same thing.

Your first query will simply check if `level` is either 1, 2, 4 or 8.

Your second query, or actually something like:

```
SELECT ... WHERE (`level` & mask) = mask LIMIT ...;
```

Has the ability to lookup `levels` that contain the mask you want and potentially some more, in your case it could be checking all value combinations between 1 and 15. Hence the performance hit.

---

As for the bruteforced benchmark @AlanFoster suggested, I don't agree with him.

It's far better to prefix the query with either:

- `EXPLAIN`, or
- `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN`

And inspect how many rows SQLite is matching.

---

### Update

#### `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM ... WHERE level IN (2, 3);`

```
SEARCH TABLE ... USING INDEX ..._level (level=?) (~20 rows)
```

#### `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM ... WHERE (level & 2) = 2;`

```
SCAN TABLE ... (~500000 rows)
```

As you can see, the bitwise AND operator needs a full-table scan.

Comment: +1 for suggesting explain and clarifying the difference between IN and & MASK

Comment: helpful investigations!

Comment: A bit old answer to a bit old question to raise a new debate :). I think that `(level & mask) = mask` should be done in `O(klog(n))` where `k` is the bit length of the mask. A different way to ask this question is give me all the level values that have all of the bits of the mask, and if I replace bits with columns it will be: Give me all the level where columns equal to mask columns. And if I apply hash optimization on it we cal also say that it's `O(log(n))`, same performances as with `IN` query but not the same results as you mentioned.

Comment: `(level & mask) = mask` is different from what I need; what I was doing was equivalent to; `(level & mask) != 0`. All records have at most 1 bit set, an entry with level 3 is not "legal". Meanwhile `(level & mask)` with mask set to 3 selects entries level 1 and entries level 2 - same as `IN(1,2)`.